# Насколько корректно возвращать из функции несколько значений, например 10

Tags: c++, функции

Я новичок в программировании, при написании кода лабораторной работы была необходимость вернуть из функции несколько значений. Эффективно ли это или лучше написать пару-тройку других функциий и хороший ли это тон написания кода программы?

**Задание:** Нужно прочитать данные из файла
`Type Number called Duration`:

```
P 703.786.4503 33
P 703.554.0980 7
```

После сделать расчеты, и сформировать выходной файл:

```
Peak: 3:08 23.20


Offpeak: 2:55 7.65


Card: 1:47 26.75
```

Хочу в одной функции посчитать часы, минуты, расходы для каждого из типов звонков и вернуть кортеж с `9`-ю элементами

Comment: Всё зависит от вашей задачи. И от вашего кода. на данный момент сложно понять, что конкретно в вашем случае будет лучше. Пожалуйста, добавьте ваш код  и текст задания в вопрос.

Comment: Нужно прочитать данные из файла
Type Number called Duration
-----------------------------------
P 703.786.4503       33
...
P 703.554.0980        7

После сделать расчеты, и сформировать выходной файл
Peak:                                 3:08     23.20
Offpeak:                              2:55      7.65
Card:                                 1:47     26.75
...
Хочу в одной функции посчитать часы, минуты, расходы для каждого из типов звонков и вернуть кортеж с 9-ю элементами

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, там её увидят больше участников =).

Comment: C++ в принципе не позволяет возвращать более одного значения. Другое дело, что это значение может быть составным.

Answer (score 1):

Вернуть можно объект (структуру например или контейнер) И там, естественно, может быть много чего. Абсолютно нормально возвращать из функции всё что вам нужно.
Но в вашем случае лучше передать в функцию объект для сохранения обработанных данных (по ссылке). А вернуть булевское значение свидетельствующее об успехе или неудаче.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ